# Por que no logro acceder a mi app de prueba en la play store

Tags: android, google-play-console

para los que han desarrollado apps en android y han logrado publicarla en la play store, tengo la siguiente consulta

Verán, he subido la primer versión de mi app a la play store, la subí accidentalmente como prueba cerrada (Después leí que tendría que haberla subido en prueba interna primero) y cuando recién la subí me aparecía que estaba en revisión, luego volví a la consola unos días más tarde y me sale

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero no puedo acceder a la aplicación en la play store

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya configuré la lista de testers
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y me agregué como uno, justo ayer ingresé al los enlaces que me dan bajo la pestaña de testers en la prueba cerrada y me salió esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero no puedo encontrar la app en la play store, siempre que intento ingresar me sale
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se que podría estar pasando, les dejo una imagen más que podría ser de ayuda
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

alguna ayuda?

Comment: Veo que en los canales de prueba dice que no hay testers. Agregaste el APK en el administardor de testers?

Comment: La verdad no entiendo eso, en el canal que estoy usando subí la apk asigné los testers, de hecho hay una imagen de uno de ellos que acepto la invitación pero sigue sin poder acceder, podrías explicarme cómo hacer lo que me preguntas

Comment: Te puede servir: https://medium.com/@pawardeepakv/google-play-console-internal-test-c6e4ea369ed8. Si ya hiciste todos los pasos del tutorial y sigue sin funcionar solo agregas un comentario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, si alguno pasara este problema, este es la solución (vergonzoso).
Como comenté en la pregunte, accidentalmente publique mi app en prueba cerrada en vez de hacerlo en prueba interna. Cuando intenté publicarla en prueba interna después de hacerlo en prueba cerrada, me mostraba un mensaje donde decía que la app no había cambiado desde la última vez que subí la apk y decidí no continuar intentando ahí (prueba interna).

Como último método y opción decidí cambiar la versión de mi app y volver a compilar e intentar subirla a prueba interna. Funcionó! Eso era todo lo que tenía que hacer, sin embargo, no logro entender porqué no funciona en prueba cerrada.

Espero ayudar. hasta luego!

Answer (score 1):

Si estas suscrito y obtienes el mensaje:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

puede ser que aùn no se encuentre publicada completamente para todos los usuarios.

**Pero es muy importante verificar que el email del usuario que registraste como tester sea el mismo que este firmado para descargar la app desde Google Play.**

---

Es importante también, revisar la configuración de tu app de prueba.

> **Closed testing**: Con las pruebas cerradas, puedes crear 1 o más pistas
> de pruebas cerradas para probar versiones preliminares de tu
> aplicación con tus propios grupos de evaluadores.
>
> **Open Testing**: Cree y administre versiones de prueba abiertas para que
> su aplicación esté disponible para los evaluadores. Cualquiera puede
> unirse a tus pruebas en Google Play

Si se encuentra en la pista de "Closed Testing", solo pueden probar los usuarios con email que se encuentren en un "Google Group" o en una lista predefinida de usuarios definidos por su email.

[image: Jorgesys Google Play Closed Testing]

En cambio, **si tu aplicación se encuentra en la pista "Open testing", cualquier usuario que se suscriba al programa de pruebas puede descargar tu aplicación**

[image: Jorgesys Google Play Open Testing]

Comment: Ya verifique los correos electrónicos muchas veces, aunque encontré en una sección de la consola que aún está en verificación

Comment: Exacto, tienes que esperar un poco y podrás ver la app

Answer (score 0):

por si todavía no consigues respuesta a tu pregunta te comento lo siguiente, en pruebas internas el acceso es casi inmediato para tus testers, pero cuando hacer unas pruebas cerradas debes esperar hasta que tu aplicación pase por todo el proceso de verificación por parte de google, en caso de ser aprobada, ahora si, ya los testers que elegiste tendrán acceso, el único mensaje que muestra antes de la liberación es es "En revisión - 1 código de versión" y veras una especie de reloj a la izquierda, cuando este validada te saldra una palomita y el mensaje "Disponible para verificadores específicos"

Mucho éxito con tu app.