# Que debería de hacer si mi app no puede ser accedida por los testers en la google play store

Tags: google-play, google-play-console

vuelvo de nuevo con un problema anterior.
Verán, estoy intentando publicar mi app en la play store he hice todo como sugería la console de la store pero los testers siguen sin poder acceder a mi app.

Debo decir que publique mi app el 15 de diciembre del año pasado (15/12/2020) y aun no pasa nada

[Puse más detalles en este post](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/416915/por-que-no-logro-acceder-a-mi-app-de-prueba-en-la-play-store)

Ya contacte al equipo de soporte de google play store y no he recibido respuesta aún.

Que me sugieren hacer con todo esto?

Comment: Puede ser que tu pregunte termine cerrada porque es la misma pregunta que la inicial.

Comment: @Bicho lo sé, pero no sé cómo actualizar mi pregunta y que aparezca de nuevo